# jQuery change active div onClick and with prev next

Tags: jquery

I have built a custom interactive svg map using jQuery and CSS. Everything works perfectly when I click on a map marker, it adds/removes classes to show/hide the relevant content. Now I am trying to add a new feature, Previous and Next buttons to allow a user to change locations in another way. I kind of have it working but after a few clicks it gets gummed up and the wrong divs are selected. Here is what I have so far (some example code for the map markers instead of all the polygon points):

```
<div id="map-nav">
  <a class="button prev-tab">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next-tab">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="map">
  <svg>
    <g data-dive="1" class="map-marker current">1</g>
    <g data-dive="2" class="map-marker">2</g>
    <g data-dive="3" class="map-marker">3</g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div id="1" class="map-content current">Content 1</div>
<div id="2" class="map-content">Content 2</div>
<div id="3" class="map-content">Content 3</div>
```

And the Jquery:

```
// Jquery Map
  $('.map-marker').click(function(){
        var dive_id = $(this).attr('data-dive');

        $('.map-marker').removeClass('current');
        $('.map-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+dive_id).addClass('current');
    });

  // Jquery Map Next Button
  $('.next-tab').click(function() {
   // get current tab
   var currentTab = $('.map-marker.current');
   var currentMap = $('.map-content.current');

   // get the next tab, if there is one
   var newTab = currentTab.next();
   var newMap = currentMap.prev();

   // at the end, so go to the first one
   if (newTab.length === 0) {
     newTab = $('.map-marker').first();
   }
   if (newMap.length === 0) {
     newMap = $('.map-content').first();
   }

   currentTab.removeClass('current');
   currentMap.removeClass('current');
   // add active to new tab
   newTab.addClass('current');
   newMap.addClass('current');
 });

 // Jquery Map Prev Button
 $('.prev-tab').click(function() {
   // get current tab
   var currentTab = $('.map-marker.current');
   var currentMap = $('.map-content.current');

   // get the previous tab, if there is one
   var newTab = currentTab.prev();
   var newMap = currentMap.prev();

   // at the start, so go to the last one
   if (newTab.length === 0) {
     newTab = $('.map-marker').last();
   }
   if (newMap.length === 0) {
     newMap = $('.map-content').last();
   }

   currentTab.removeClass('current');
   currentMap.removeClass('current');
   // add active to new tab
   newTab.addClass('current');
   newMap.addClass('current');
 });
```

As I said, the first click function where I am changing markers/content by clicking the marker works perfectly. Its the next and previous buttons not working quite right. I also believe there is probably a much better way to implement the next and previous buttons but this is what I have come up with. Any suggestions for improvement would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify what behavior you're looking for? I might also suggest only including the relevant code. From what you've posted, I don't see anything with class= 'next-tab', so that listener would never fire.

Comment: sorry i updated the code to show the controls. when a user clicks on a .map-marker, the .map-content with the relevant id is displayed. I want to add a function to allow the user to hit next and previous buttons to show the content in addition to being able to click on the markers. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If I post into a jsfiddle it seems to work in that if I console.log the newTab item, I get the expected output. If possible, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest simple iteration via the list of `map-content` objects using your own index. This will add flexibility by not having your code directly dependent on the HTML markup you have.

The provided snippet also handles as many markers as you want and they will be picked up automatically, so you don't have to list them manually.

```js
$(function() {
  //Slide IDs
  var slides = [];
  //Get all markers from the map and put them to array
  $('svg > .map-marker').each(function() {
    slides.push($(this).attr('data-dive'));
  });
  //Index of currently displayed slide
  var currentSlide = 0;
  //Show the inital slide
  $('.map-content').hide();
  $('#' + slides[currentSlide]).show();

  //Click on markers on the map will show the specific slide
  $('.map-marker').on('click', function() {
    //First we get the data-dive attribute
    let diveId = $(this).attr('data-dive');
    //Now we hide all content items shown
    $('.map-content').hide();
    //And show the chosen one
    $('#' + diveId).show();
    //And set the current slide to that value so the next and prev buttons
    //can navigate from that point
    currentSlide = slides.indexOf(diveId);
    return false;
  });

  //Click on each button does basically the same,
  //except the direction of the move
  $('a.next-tab, a.prev-tab').on('click', function() {
    //We check whether or not we clicked on next or prev and increase
    //or decrease the slide number accordingly
    if ($(this).hasClass('prev-tab')) currentSlide--;
    else currentSlide++;
    //Next we check for the boundaries and adjust it accordingly
    if (currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
    if (currentSlide >= slides.length) currentSlide = 0;
    //Hide all shown content items
    $('.map-content').hide();
    //Show the next(or prev) one
    $('#' + slides[currentSlide]).show();
    return false;
  });
})
```

```css
div.map-content {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.map-marker {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.current {
  display: block;
}

.map {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: green;
}

a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-nav">
  <a href="#" class="button prev-tab">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="button next-tab">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="map">
  <svg>
    <g data-dive="1" class="map-marker current">
      <circle cx="20" cy="25" r="20" fill="blue" />
      <text x="15" y="30" fill="white">1</text>
    </g>
    <g data-dive="2" class="map-marker">
      <circle cx="70" cy="25" r="20" fill="blue" />
      <text x="65" y="30" fill="white">2</text>
    </g>
    <g data-dive="3" class="map-marker">
      <circle cx="120" cy="25" r="20" fill="blue" />
      <text x="115" y="30" fill="white">3</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div id="1" class="map-content">Content 1</div>
<div id="2" class="map-content">Content 2</div>
<div id="3" class="map-content">Content 3</div>
```

Comment: This is working pretty well, I just need one change. I have to use addClass and removeClass because this is inside of a jQuery tab, and otherwise the height doesn't load currently. So I have made those changes and it is working, except I can't figure out how to make the markers add a class using the prev and next function. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fnwL8x2q/25/

Comment: @RiotAct you just need to change `$('data-dive' + slides[currentSlide]).addClass('current');` to `$('.map-marker[data-dive="' + slides[currentSlide]+'"]').addClass('current');` in your line `45`. 


Other than that you nailed it, good job!


Check here - [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Sweet! Thank you very much for your help! This does exactly what I want and uses less and cleaner jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `:eq` selector along with jQuery's `$.index()` method? You'll need to add a container element to the `.map-content` divs though:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var length = $('.map-content').length; // number of elements

  $('.map-marker').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(); // click element's place
    // handle classes
    $('.map-marker,.map-content').removeClass('current');
    $('.map-content:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    // show/hide depending on index  
    if (index == 0) {
      $('.prev-tab').hide();
      $('.next-tab').show();
    } else if (index == (length - 1)) {
      $('.prev-tab').show();
      $('.next-tab').hide();
    } else {
      $('.prev-tab,.next-tab').show();
    }
  });

  $('.next-tab').click(function() {
    var currentIndex = $('.map-content.current').index(); // get index
    var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1; // add 1
    // manage classes
    $('.map-marker, .map-content').removeClass('current');
    $('.map-content:eq(' + nextIndex + '),.map-marker:eq(' + nextIndex + ')').addClass('current');
    // hide next if last
    if (nextIndex == (length - 1)) {
      $(this).hide();
      $('.prev-tab').show();
    }
  });

  $('.prev-tab').click(function() {
    var currentIndex = $('.map-content.current').index(); // get index
    var prev = currentIndex - 1; // add 1
    // manage classes
    $('.map-marker, .map-content').removeClass('current');
    $('.map-content:eq(' + prev + '),.map-marker:eq(' + prev + ')').addClass('current');
    // hide prev if first
    if (prev == 0) {
      $(this).hide();
      $('.next-tab').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.current {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.map span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

.map-content-container {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.prev-tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map">
  <span class="map-marker current">1</span>
  <span class="map-marker">2</span>
  <span class="map-marker">3</span>
</div>

<div class="map-content-container">
  <div class="map-content current">Content 1</div>
  <div class="map-content">Content 2</div>
  <div class="map-content">Content 3</div>
</div>

<div class="prev-tab">Prev</div>
<div class="next-tab">Next</div>
```

The `index()` will return the place inside the parent div which will give you enough info to toggle the classes (and add or substract `1` so you move forwards and backwards throught the list using the `:eq()` pseudo-class). You can also add a small conditional to hide the `.prev/-next` tabs when you are at the beginning/end of the count.

**NOTES:**
  - Remember `index` is zero-based
  - Try not to use number only ids in your html elements

Comment: can this be made as a loop? like the last next repeats to the first item?

Comment: Yes. Instead of hiding the Next/Prev tabs, you could change the `index` manually. For example, `next-tab`: `if (currentIndex == length ){ var nextIndex = 0 } else { var nextIndex = currentIndex+1 }`

Comment: I would use the ternary operator though: `var nextIndex = (currentIndex == length) ? 0 : currentIndex +1`